# Azure DevOps is it possible to group builds which are in queue

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have multiple check in happening in our dev branch and each checking triggers a build. this causes a log of queue in the builds.

It is possible to setup in such a way all the builds in the queue could be clubbed together and built?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! in the build trigger options when you check the "Enable continues integration" you have another check box:

**[ ] Batch changes while a build is in progress**.

[image]

Just check it :)

If you are using `.yaml` builds just add this to the `trigger` section:

```
batch: true
```